# PhpStorm: open a project/folder with command in current version

Tags: command-line, terminal, phpstorm

I've used the command `phpstorm [path]` to open a project/folder with PhpStorm.

After the update from 2018.2 to 2018.3 the command opens every project/folder with the older version 2018.2

**How can I fix it, that the command opens the current version?**

Comment: update the phpstorm command to the .3 installation?

Comment: @treyBake sounds good, how do I do that?

Comment: Depends on how you've set up the phpstorm command - is it an alias in `.bashrc`? Is it in your PATH variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tools > Create Command-line Launcher…` from within the current version and then just overwrite it.